# Azure Static IP for VPN?

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

I am establishing a site to site vpn from on prem to Azure, however, i cannot assign a static public ip to it.  Per this link, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm, it's designed that way.  Can someone please explain why and what if the dynamic ip changes on azure end?  Then the site-site vpn breaks.  Unless Azure assumes the tunnel is always running, it will keep that dynamic IP.

VPN gateways
An Azure VPN Gateway connects an Azure virtual network to other Azure virtual networks, or to an on-premises network. A public IP address is assigned to the VPN Gateway to enable it to communicate with the remote network. You can only assign a dynamic basic public IP address to a VPN gateway.

Comment: Even when you set the allocation method to static, you cannot specify the actual IP address assigned to the public IP address resource. Azure assigns the IP address from a pool of available IP addresses in the Azure location the resource is created in.

Answer (score 3):

The only time the VPN gateway IP address changes is when the gateway is deleted and re-created. The VPN gateway public IP address doesn't change across resizing, resetting, or other internal maintenance/upgrades of your VPN gateway.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-vpn-faq#can-i-request-a-static-public-ip-address-for-my-vpn-gateway):

> zone-redundant and zonal gateways (gateway SKUs that have AZ in the
> name) both rely on a Standard SKU Azure public IP resource. Azure
> Standard SKU public IP resources must use a static allocation method.
>
> For non-zone-redundant and non-zonal gateways (gateway SKUs that do
> not have AZ in the name), only dynamic IP address assignment is
> supported. However, this doesn't mean that the IP address changes
> after it has been assigned to your VPN gateway. The only time the VPN
> gateway IP address changes is when the gateway is deleted and then
> re-created. The VPN gateway public IP address doesn't change when you
> resize, reset, or complete other internal maintenance and upgrades of
> your VPN gateway.